# Can't delete all from Sequelize n:m associated table

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am trying to delete all contents from a n:m association table.
I have the tables: MenuItems and UserGroups like this, but I am using migrations to genererate the database:

MenuItems

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const MenuItems = sequelize.define('MenuItems', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
 // more fields...
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });
  MenuItems.associate = function(models) {
    MenuItems.belongsToMany(models.UserGroups, { through: 'MenuItemUserGroups' });
  };
```

UserGroups

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserGroups = sequelize.define('UserGroups', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });
  UserGroups.associate = function(models) {
    // Associations to other models 
    UserGroups.belongsToMany(models.MenuItems, { through: 'MenuItemUserGroups' });
  };
  return UserGroups;
};
```

The association table is generated with the following migration:

```
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  return queryInterface.createTable('MenuItemUserGroups', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    menuItemId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'MenuItems',
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    },
    userGroupId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'UserGroups',
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    }
    //more fields
  });
}
```

I try to delete using the following sequelize code:

```
models.MenuItems.findOne({ where: { id: 1 }, include: [{ all: true }] }).then(menuItem => {
  if(req.body.userGroups.length <= 0) {
    menuItem.setUserGroups([]).then(result => {
      console.log(result);   
    });
```

The SQL that is generated is the following:

```
DELETE FROM `MenuItemUserGroups` WHERE `UserGroupId` = 1 AND `MenuItemId` IN (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
[ 0 ]
```

where UserGroupId IN (NULL) will always return nothing. If that part is removed, the query works.

Could this have something to do with some naming convention?

Comment: what version of sequelize do you use? I made a testing with your code with sequelize 5.9.2 and it works. Generated query is `Executing (default): DELETE FROM "MenuItemUserGroups" WHERE "MenuItemId" = 1 AND "UserGroupId" IN (1)
`. Try update version or try to use a `removeUserGroups()` function

Comment: Sorry, I have been away, I tried now with version 5.12.2 and still experience same problem. I tried using removeUserGroups() as well but get the same SQL